# SQL Left outer join with compound key

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Employee.A - List of Employees
Table Phone.B    - Employee Phone Number

Each Employee has ONLY one phone number in Phone Table, Sometimes no phone

I want to Join Employee Table to Phone Table and bring back all Employees that includes the phone number regardless if phone number exists.

```
SELECT A.EmployeeName, B.PhoneNumber
FROM Employee A LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone B
    ON A.EmployeeId= B.EmployeeId
```

Compound Key Employee

- EmployeeOrg
- EmployeeId

Compound Key Phone

- EmployeeOrg
- EmployeeId
- PhoneId

My Question is how to include the compound key.
I thought it would be this... but this did not work as I expected. It is bringing back Employees from Other org (organizations) other then 1. On the image below you can see org 5 returned. why?

```
SELECT A.EmployeeName, B.PhoneNumber
FROM Employee A LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone B
    ON A.EmployeeOrg = 1
   and A.EmployeeOrg = B.EmployeeOrg
   and A.EmployeeId  = B.EmployeeId
```

[image: My Query result - I know the field names are different]

Comment: As you described it, your `LEFT JOIN` that you thought would work, should be correct.  Why do you think this didn't work?

Comment: what you mean by doesn't work actually? be specific

Comment: What was the error you received? Your first query should have worked based on the information provided.

Comment: Nevermind, It did work, Once I included the ORG part of the Key I guess it affected the sort.
The query without the ORG returned the records with phone on top of list
The query with the ORG as part of key, I did not. So i missed it that it had been returned..sorry

Comment: Then delete the question ....

Comment: I though it was working, but am still getting weird results. I just noticed it is bring records from other ORGS.... The org is part of the compound employee key which is employeeOrg employeeId

Comment: Some of the Employees are in other Organizations. I do not want them included

Comment: Add a minimum sample data to check the result.

Comment: I uploaded an image of the data.
It seems I was missing the WHERE Clause
Where =  A.EmployeeOrg = 1

but since I am doing a join should t not be 
Where  A.EmployeeOrg = 1
    and   A.EmployeeOrg = B.EmployeeOrg